# Function that update the salary

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to create a function (or if there is any more efficient way to do it) that will update the SMALLEST sal FROM emp with 0.01.

I tried a few ways to do it but can't figure out.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sal RETURN NUMBER; 
    IS  emp.sal NUMBER; 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE emp 
       SET emp.sal = (SELECT MIN(emp.sal) FROM emp) * 0,1); 
END update_sal;
```

Any sugestions please?

Answer (score 1):

Your function has lots of syntax errors, and since you are not actually returning anything, you need to use a procedure.

```
create or replace procedure update_sal
is
  begin
    update emp
    set sal = sal * .01
    where sal = (select min(sal) from emp);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is more what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sal RETURN NUMBER
IS  emp.sal NUMBER; 
BEGIN     
  UPDATE emp 
  SET emp.sal = emp.sal * 0,1
  WHERE emp.sal = (SELECT MIN(e.sal) FROM emp e)
END update_sal;
```

you were trying to restrict and update at the same time, in the SET. Restrict with WHERE, use the SET to change the value.

As a rule of thumb, if your UPDATE ends up with no WHERE clause, something is wrong.

Comment: As per @OldProgrammers spot, you should declare this a *procedure* rather than as a *function*.